# Windows Kerberos Authentication for Google Chrome and Edge

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, authentication, kerberos, windows-authentication

I am using Kerberos authentication protocol for my websites.

I have added website under `trusted sites` and `intranet sites` and updated `Group policy` under `Internet Options`.

It works well in `IE` but does not work with `Chrome` and `Edge`. It keeps asking for credentials and yields to `401` error code.

I researched a lot and got to know that for `Chrome`, it works well with `NTLM` but for `Chrome` to work with `Kerberos` we need to do some settings using cmd.

ie. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” --auth-server-whitelist="*.domain.com " --auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist="*.domain.com"`

After doing this my website keeps loading round.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone struggling with Google Chrome, it worked after adding below values to `Registry`.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*.yourwebsitedomain.com"
"AuthServerWhitelist"="*.yourwebsitedoman.com"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*.yourwebsitedomain.com"
"AuthServerWhitelist"="*.yourwebsitedoman.com"
```

This setting does not work in Chrome `Incognito`.
For `Incognito` to work with `Kerberos` protocol,we need to update the Flag value under `chrome://flags`
`Enable Ambient Authentication in Incognito mode` to `Enabled`.
Finding solutions for Edge. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that the policies have been renamed to [`AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist) and [`AuthServerAllowlist`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AuthServerAllowlist). The [documentation on chromium policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates/) gives a little more insight on how to set these policies.